# How to have fake camera device on Ubuntu without having an actual physical camera?

Tags: ubuntu, camera

I'm writing a module that relies chrome to allow access to camera. However, this will be deployed to computers without actual camera device thus google chrome won't even ask for permission.

Note that using chrome parameters to start is not an option. I need to install something in ubuntu that will serve as fake camera device that chrome can detect.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser! Frankly, this sounds a lot like a like a [X-Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you clarify? What "module" are you writing? How does it interact with Chrome? And why does it insist on using the camera?

Comment: @sleske Actually its a bit hack-y. We have this module that requires either camera or mic turned on for it to hear from another connection. Now "listening" function should disable the mic, hence camera should be on. Our team decided not to fix the core problem as it will waste lots of our time. Rather we want it to work as it is for the meantime while we rewrite the entire new system. So a quick solution is to install a fake camera device thing.. or get an actual camera which will confuse our consumers of why would there be a camera when it is not being used.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I still don't quite understand the situation, but I'll try to write an answer

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/).

That is a Linux kernel module that simulates a webcam.

It is reasonably well documented, and should not be difficult to get running.

For details, also see this question on our Unix & Linux site: [How can I stream my desktop/screen to /dev/video1 as a (fake) “webcam” on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528400/how-can-i-stream-my-desktop-screen-to-dev-video1-as-a-fake-webcam-on-linux)